# Automatically updating .txt with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

As i'm new to web programming, i have some questions.
I'd like to implement a very basic chat displayed on my index.php.

It's basically a *.txt-file that should get reloaded automaticalle every second.

My code for now:

```html
<script>
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"

$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});
function getLog() {
$.ajax({
    url: 'chat.txt',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function(text) {
        $("#chat").text(text);
        setTimeout(getLog, 1000); // refresh every second
       }
    })
}
getLog();
</script>

(...)
<div class="panel panel-default">
 <div class="panel-heading"><strong>Soloranking.de 
          Chat</strong></div>
   <div id="chat">
   </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

My problem is, that nothing it being displayed and i lack on solutions now.
I bet it's just a little mistake, but i'd appreciate your help :)

Kind Regards,
Jan

Comment: You haven't told us your question / problem yet. :P

Comment: Oh well, it wont work :D i dont get the text field displayed :D

Comment: Check the console for errors. Also, how are you writing to the text file?

Comment: Console says: "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (index):7"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `src` attribute should be located inside the `script` tag. Also, all the code should be located within the `$(document).ready()` function.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       function getLog() {
           $.ajax({
               url: 'chat.txt',
               dataType: 'text',
               success: function(text) {
                   $("#chat").text(text);
                   setTimeout(getLog, 1000); // refresh every second
               }
           })
        }

    getLog(); 
    });
</script>


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <strong>Soloranking.de Chat</strong>
    </div>
    <div id="chat"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No problem ;) Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js

Add this library for jquery run.

Your $ is not deifine.

Comment: Library added, no more console errors. But according to my followed ajax tutorials, i do define it o.O

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

If still it does not work then add jquery library from cdn.

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put the method parameter in your Ajax request